# Interacting with bound DTO using MVVM

Tags: c#

I'm currently Binding my Listbox to a DTO. Following MVVM patterns, How do I interact with what was selected from the Listbox.

I want something like this  [1 being the "FileName"

```
If (Listbox.Selecteditem[1] == "samplefilename")
{ Messagebox.Show("Files matched"}
```

But how exactly is that done using MVVM? Do I have to create SelectedValue bindings/properties?

```
public class FilesDTO : IDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileArray { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a "SelectedFileDTO" to your ViewModel and in your XAML, make sure it's set to TwoWay. When it changes in the View, your SelectedFileDTO setter will be hit in your ViewModel.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource={Binding Files} SelectedItem={Binding SelectedFileDTO, Mode=TwoWay}/>

public FilesDTO SelectedFileDTO
{
   get...
   set...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should bind the `SelectedValue` property to a `DependencyProperty`. Then whenever you want to use it, it is right there at your disposal. You could also give the `DependencyProperty` changed events to utilize.